# Apache Camel in-memory dead letter queue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am looking for a simple delayed retried delivery on my camel route. I have configured

```
from("rss:" + rssUrl + "?splitEntries=false&delay=15s").bean(rssHandler) .onException(ConnectException.class).redeliveryDelay(10000).backOffMultiplier(2).maximumRedeliveries(5);
```

on my route, but after seeing that it did not work I learned that I must configure a dead letter channel, otherwise this configuration is ignored basically.

So I added:

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:error"));
```

to my Java Camel config, however, I am looking for the simplest possible dead letter channel implementation that does not require me to pull in say ActiveMQ or anything like that, I'd be happy with a simple memory-based retry mechanism with no guarantees. Unfortunately, I haven't found any so far, so reaching out to here if anyone can help me pointing to a simple way to configure retries with some minimal dead letter channel component.

Comment: is the route and the errorHandler configuration in the same routebuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a seda component instead of a log component can give you an in-memory dead letter destination. E.g. replace "log" with "seda". However, keep in mind that once the re-deliveries are exhausted, the message will live in this queue, and hence in memory unless there is a process de-queuing it or purging messages older than specified time period configured for this queue.

https://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

You can also, just configure your config to mark the exception as handled and give up on the message once the max re-delivery count is reached